# How to get SharePoint to “see” new SQL Views, Tables and Stored Procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010

I’m trying to define new external content types, I’m able to connect to SQL Server and define external content types from tables, stored procedures and views that were already in the database.

The problem I’m having is that I created a new SQL View in SQL Server with the data I want, but when I try to define a new content type, SharePoint doesn’t show me the new SQL View in Data Source Explorer.

I thought it could possibly be the way the SQL view was created, so I created a new test Table, a new stored procedure but that didn’t work either.

I tried “Refresh All” and deleting and re-creating the connection in Data Source Explorer, but nothing seems to work.

It seems that any views, tables or stored procedures that I created after a certain point in time are not available in SharePoint

I’m using SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services (64bit)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Silvio

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct SQL Server? Check your connection string.